# Does Postgres hav an equivalent of 'mysqldump --where'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm working on a Rails project which uses the multi-tenanting gem [Milia](https://github.com/dsaronin/milia).  Milia uses row-based tenanting, meaning that every row in the database has a column named `tenant_id` which determines who this data belongs to.  We use Heroku and Postgresql.

The database as a whole is very large, and while there are times when I want the full production dump, much more often I would rather have only data for one tenant.

So then I'd like to dump the whole db, but only rows `where tenant_id=x`. `mysqldump` has a [`where`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where) condition, but I can't find an equivalent for Postgresql.

for example, if my database is like this:

```
Table Members  
tenant_id, id, name, sex  
1, 1, joe, m  
1, 2, sally, f  
2, 3, bob, m  

Table Jobs  
tenant_id, id
1, 1
1, 2
2, 3
```

and I want to dump all the tables where `tenant_id` is `1`, I would expect to get back a dump containing the following:

```
Table Members  
tenant_id, id, name, sex  
1, 1, joe, m  
1, 2, sally, f  

Table Jobs  
tenant_id, id
1, 1
1, 2
```

Comment: All I can think of here is the COPY command, which sounds like it would be a lot of hard work.

Comment: there isn't an equivalent for pg_dump. COPY within a for loop is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best practice, but you can:

1. create a [view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createview.html) of the table with rows you want

`CREATE VIEW tweets AS SELECT * FROM contents WHERE provider = 'twitter';`

2. create a new table from the view

`CREATE TABLE tweets_table AS SELECT * FROM tweets;`

3. in another tab, dump the new table

`pg_dump -t tweets_table brainstream_development`

4. delete the intermediate table

Another option is to create the view and copy from it [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-psql.html) (psql can import that):

`CREATE VIEW tweets AS SELECT * FROM contents WHERE provider = 'twitter';`

`psql -d brainstream_development -A -t -c "select * from tweets" > tweets.dump`

Comment: thanks for your answer.  this is only table by table, but i want to filter at the database level.  i'll edit the question to make it more clear